# Reverse Google Client ID with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, reverse, google-signin

How to reverse the Google Client ID programmatically to have the iOS URL scheme as result (not reversing the string but the ID order) e.g.:

`ClientID = "xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"`

**ClientID**, after reversing, should result in **URLscheme** that looks like:

`URLscheme = "com.googleusercontent.apps.xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reversing Google Client ID to iOS URL scheme** with Swift (create Client ID for iOS):

```
    // GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx‌​xxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"

    let urlScheme="com.googleusercontent.apps.xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx‌​xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    let urlSchemeArr = urlScheme.characters.split{$0 == "."}.map(String.init)
    let GoogleClientIDarr = urlSchemeArr.reverse()
    let GoogleClientID = GoogleClientIDarr.joinWithSeparator(".")
    print(GoogleClientID);

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID=GoogleClientID;
```

Comment: - Thanks bbum and Jay! ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. Split the string at the '.'
2. Reverse order of the resulting array
3. Join the array back into a string using '.'

There is API on NSString and NSArray to do (1) and (3).   (2) is straightforward.

Comment: the only issue with this that I'm not a Swift programmer and being weekend, everyone is gone, have to get this done alone. I can figure it out but will take a long while, this is why asking for help :D - thanks anyway!

Comment: got as far as:

`let GoogleClientID = "com.googleusercontent.apps.xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

let GoogleClientIDarr = GoogleClientID.characters.split{$0 == "."}.map(String.init)

let GoogleClientIDarr = GoogleClientIDarr.reverse()

let URLscheme = ".".join(GoogleClientIDarr)`

Answer (score 0):

Goto > Project  - info - url types
 delete all the urls if not needed then code will upload.

Comment: seems offtopic, question was asking to do this `programmatically`

Comment: ya I also added 'if not needed' ,  so why to waste time on programatically.